# How to Add multi lookup field client object model using javascript sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I will add multi Lookup values:

```
var items = List.getItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.load(items);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function(sender, args) {
        var itemEnum = items.getEnumerator();

        // if we have an item, update it
        if (itemEnum.moveNext()) {
            // update the item
            var current = itemEnum.get_current();

            //update item lookup
            var lookups = [];

            for (var ii in lookupsIds) {

                var lookupValue = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
                lookupValue.set_lookupId(lookupsIds[ii]);
                lookups.push(lookupValue);

            }
            console.log(lookups);
            current.set_item('Category', lookups);
            current.update();
            clientContext.load(current);
```

output  :

(3) [SP.FieldLookupValue, SP.FieldLookupValue, SP.FieldLookupValue]
0: SP.FieldLookupValue {$1s_1: "3"}
1: SP.FieldLookupValue {$1s_1: ","}
2: SP.FieldLookupValue {$1s_1: "4"}
length: 3
**proto**: Array(0)

my problem, the values ​​of lookups (3,4) do not add in the list

Comment: Can you also paste the part of the code where you assign the value to the lookupsIds variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var clientContext;
var collListItem;
$(document).ready(function () {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
        // the list name
        var listName = "cl03";                                  
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.load(collListItem);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.updateLookups),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );                             
    });    
});

function updateLookups(sender, args) { 
    // lookup ids
    var lookupsIds = [3,4];
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    // iterate items
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var lookupVals = [];
        lookupsIds.forEach(function (id) {
            var lookupVal = new SP.FieldLookupValue();
            lookupVal.set_lookupId(id);
            lookupVals.push(lookupVal);
        });

        oListItem.set_item('Category',lookupVals);
        oListItem.update();
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        );

    }

}
function onQuerySucceeded()  
{  
    console.log('Updated Successfully');  
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
    '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
```